# map on a scala List/Seq

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have the below simple code

```
private def tt(l:Seq[Int]):Seq[Future[Unit]] = {
    val aa = l.map(_=>Future.successful(()))
    aa
  }
```

I can easily grasp the fact that I am returning `Future[Unit] type corresponding to each element of my sequence "l" that is passed to method tt.` It is easy to say that `"aa"` is of type `Seq[Future[Unit]]` as a consequence. What I am unable to get my head around is that when my "l", the sequence is of length zero, map will never be executed, why and how even then am I able to get Seq[Future[Unit]]because I have explicitly put the return type and clearly scala is happy that no matter what is "l" even if empty, "aa' will still result with Seq[Future[Unit]]. But I fail to get why

Comment: Well an empty Seq can form any type really. It's just empty. Doesn't matter if it has zero `Int`s or zero `Future[Unit]`s. It's still nothing. It's the same with `None` and `Option`, an empty Option can be of any type whatsoever, because it has no actual values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ...when my "l", the sequence is of length zero, map will never be executed....

The above statement is incorrect. `map`, when called on an empty sequence, *is* executed: calling `map` on an empty sequence returns an empty sequence.

When you pass an empty `Seq` to `tt`, the return type is indeed `Seq[Future[Unit]]`. What is returned is a `Seq[Future[Unit]]` that is empty:

```
scala> def tt(l:Seq[Int]):Seq[Future[Unit]] = {
 |     val aa = l.map(_=>Future.successful(()))
 |     aa
 |   }
tt: (l: Seq[Int])Seq[scala.concurrent.Future[Unit]]

scala> tt(Seq())
res0: Seq[scala.concurrent.Future[Unit]] = List()
```

In the above code, `map` *is* executed on `l`, even when `l` is empty.

It's the same with calling `map` on an empty `Seq` of any type. For example, to convert a `Seq[String]` to a `Seq[Int]`:

```
scala> Seq[String]().map(_.toInt)
res2: Seq[Int] = List()
```

The result of calling `.map(_.toInt)` on an empty `Seq[String]` is an empty `Seq[Int]`.